# Axios PUT request with header payload and Basic Authntication fails

Tags: node.js, axios, http-put

I am not able to get the node.js `axios` HTTP PUT request working with `Authentication Basic <credentials>` header. I did try below two approaches but in both the cases I get authentication failure.

**Method #1**

```
const name = '<email>';
const pass = '<pass>';

// Base64 string for credentials 
const credentials = `${name}:${pass}`;
const baseCredentials = Buffer.from(credentials, 'base64');

// Payload
const params = {
    key: 'value'
}

// Headers
const headers = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(params).length,
      'Authorization': 'Basic '+baseCredentials
    }
};

// Put request 
const result = await axios.put(hostUrl, params, headers);

// Server responds with `HTTP 400 Bad Request`.
```

**Method #2**

```
const name = '<email>';
const pass = '<pass>';

// Payload
const params = {
    key: 'value'
}

// Headers
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(params).length
};

// Put request 
const result = await axios({
  headers: headers,
  method: "put",
  url: hostUrl,
  auth: {
    username: name,
    password: pass,
  },
  data: params
});

// Server responds with `HTTP 400 Bad Request`.
```

I am not sure if there is issue with sequence of the parameters passed to `axios`.
Same URL with same credentials works well from the `postman`.

Comment: You don't need to pass `Content-Length` in headers. and If it is working in postman then copy the code from postman and try that. You might be missing something

Comment: Not sure if postman provides axios code. Content length, if I don't send in the header then it is not received at the server end.

Comment: Postman provides the code. See on the right side bar. there will a code icon something like this **</>** click on that and choose language from dropdown.